# Unable to create a xamarin project on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2022

When I am trying to create a Xamarin project I get the following error:

> Could not load the file or assembly 'Xamarin.VisualStudio.Contracts',Version=16.8.4.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'3 or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: First, please check that you have install all the packages and SDKs. After that, if you still have this issue, repair the Visual Stuido.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.